# Complete Atomic Boolean algebras in Coq

Tags: coq

In CoqId I have entered `Variables s p e t f: Type.`

I now want the set of elements which interpret terms of type `e` to have the structure of a Complete Atomic Boolean algebra. Of course, for this to be the case we need there to be a bottom element BOT and a top element TOP amongst the set of elements which interpret terms of type `e`. That is, the set of elements which interpret terms of type `e` must form a Boolean algebra where every subset of it must have a join (a supremum), and where for any element of this Boolean algebra which is not BOT, there is an element c which is not BOT and which is such that it is not the case that there is an element d which is not BOT and such that c is below d in the ordering of the Boolean algebra.

I realise these are semantic conditions on the interpretation of terms, with c,d BOT and TOP being the model-theoretic interpretation of terms of type `e`.

My question is then what I need to do in CoqId in order to make sure that the terms of type `e` behave in such a way that the set of elements which are model-theoretic interpretations them form a Complete, Atomic Boolean algebra. I suppose I will need a term denoting BOT and a term denoting TOP, an ordering relation amongst terms of type `e`, an operator which forms the sum of an arbitrary subset of terms of type `e` and a negation operator on terms of type `e`.

If any of you have any ideas, I would be very interested.

---

I feel that the answer to this question is that I needn't worry about this in CoqId, since these are model-theoretic conditions on the interpretation of types. Rather, all I need are terms in Coq which represent sum, the top element, the bottom element and negation on type `e`, and then it is left to model theory to bother about the interpretations of these terms being a complete, Atomic Boolean algebra. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed right: what you probably want is to axiomatize the atomic boolean algebra structure on e, i.e. assume that there are various constants such as `bot : e`, a relation `le_e : e -> -> Prop`. But if you want to reason internally in Coq, you might also want to axiomatize the atomic boolean algebra structure, for instance assume an axiom `bot_is_bot : forall x : e, le_e bot x`, and similarly for all other properties of the structure you want to look at. That way, a model of your theory *has* to be an atomic boolean algebra, because it has to interpret all the axioms, which exactly correspond to having this structure.